# Speed up R Focal Function

Tags: r, parallel-processing, gis, raster, moving-average

I am running a Focal function in R calculating the mode within my moving window. This is being run on a large raster with a cell size of 56m (see details below).

```
class       : RasterLayer 
dimensions  : 63091, 52410, 3306599310  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution  : 56, 56  (x, y)
extent      : -1575288, 1359672, -1486356, 2046740  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=aea +lat_1=44.75 +lat_2=55.75 +lat_0=40 +lon_0=-96 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
data source : D:dataPath\rasterFile.tif 
names       : int17_5001 
values      : 0, 500  (min, max)
```

This has worked great when using smaller window sizes like 29 or 15x see below. These completed after about 48hrs.

```
29xFocal <- focal(
  myRasterInput,
  w=matrix(1,nrow=29,ncol=29),
  fun=modal
  )


15xFocal <- focal(
  myRasterInput,
  w=matrix(1,nrow=15,ncol=15),
  fun=modal
  )
```

The issue is when I try and run this for larger windows.. Specifically, I need to use a window size of ~ 180x and 300x. These have been running for almost a week and have not finished.

Any suggestions for a better way to run a focal function with larger windows on these datasets?

Answer (score 0):

Generally, the package `terra` is supposed to replace `raster`. Doing that can already increase speed by a lot (I found a blog showing e.g. a speed up by x7 for the computationally demanding reprojection).

The switch is basically adjusting to a slightly different syntax, everything else, including the focal function, will be the same.

Also, there are other packages:

1. There also is a parallel implementation of `focal`: `fasterFocal()`, see [here](https://rdrr.io/github/adamlilith/fasterRaster/man/fasterFocal.html). I haven't tested it though and as the author states on the respective github page, this replaces `raster` functions (with GRASS GIS implementations) and may be obsolote since the arrival of `terra`, but in some cases may still be faster.
2. There is an unmaintained package "velox" that allows for significantly faster focal filters. You can try to install it from archives:

```
require("devtools")

packageurl <- "https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/velox/velox_0.2.0.tar.gz"
install.packages(packageurl, repos=NULL, type="source")
```

And then convert your raster to a velox object, do your focal operation and convert it back:

```
library(velox)
library(raster)

r_vx = velox(r)
r$medianFocal(wrow=50, wcol=50, bands=1)
r_filtered = r_vx$as.RasterLayer()
```